# How can I take a picture of code like this

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3000

I want to take a picture of programming code like this:

[image]

I have a Nikon D3000 with two lens, a `AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G` `and a AF-S DX VR Zoom-Nikkor 55-200mm f/4-5.6G IF-ED`. Which one should I use and what should I do to get this effect? If this effect is not possible in-camera, how can I get it?

I must emphasize that I'm not a pro photographer (evidently).

Comment: It looks like this is just a photo of some HTML displayed on a CRT monitor. Is that correct, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: This looks a lot like it came from here. http://instacod.es/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is which lens focuses the closest. If you have a macro function on either lens use that one. 
Test both lens by putting them on manual focus and racking the lens out and leave it. Then move the camera back and forth toward your monitor to see which focuses that closest. 
Once you have established the closest focusing lens put it on a tripod or a box to steady the camera.
Photograph starting at 1/30 of a second and move slower(1/15, 1/8) if you get any flicker or lines.
Do not use a flash or let the pop up flash good off.
Remember you can always crop closer in Photoshop or an editing program.

Comment: DSLR lenses have no macro function, they have a minimum focus distance.

Comment: @Itai My Tamron 70-300 had to be switched into macro range (and the lens had to be set to the longer end of the range to do so).

Comment: Many older SLR "macro" zoom lenses required a switch to be flipped with the lens at maximum focal length to allow the barrel to extend enough to ficus at the minimum distance. Not nearly as common with lenses designed specifically for DSLRs per se.